# FizzBuzz with Active Patterns

Tags: f#, fizzbuzz, active-pattern

I'm trying to understand Active Patterns, so I'm playing around with FizzBuzz:

```
let (|Fizz|_|) i = if i % 3 = 0 then Some Fizz else None
let (|Buzz|_|) i = if i % 5 = 0 then Some Buzz else None
let (|FizzBuzz|_|) i = if i % 5 = 0 && i % 3 = 0 then Some FizzBuzz else None

let findMatch = function
    | Some Fizz -> "Fizz"
    | Some Buzz -> "Buzz"
    | Some FizzBuzz -> "FizzBuzz"
    | _ -> ""

let fizzBuzz = seq {for i in 0 .. 100 -> Some i}
                |> Seq.map (fun i -> i, findMatch i)
```

Is this basically the right approach, or is there a better way to use Active Patterns here?  Shouldn't I be able to make `findMatch` take an int instead of int option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `findMatch` function should be:

```
let findMatch = function
    | FizzBuzz -> "FizzBuzz" (* should be first, as pad pointed out *)
    | Fizz -> "Fizz"
    | Buzz -> "Buzz"
    | _ -> ""
```

You can rewrite the last few lines:

```
let fizzBuzz = Seq.init 100 (fun i -> i, findMatch i)
```

Your active patterns are fine. One alternative is to use a complete active pattern:

```
let (|Fizz|Buzz|FizzBuzz|Num|) i = 
    match i % 3, i % 5 with
    | 0, 0 -> FizzBuzz
    | 0, _ -> Fizz
    | _, 0 -> Buzz
    | _ -> Num i
```

Answer (score 10):

Daniel's first solution can be simplified, because you don't actually need to define a separate active pattern for `FizzBuzz`. The case can be described as both `Fizz` and `Buzz` matching, which can be nicely expressed in the pattern language:

```
let findMatch = function 
  | Fizz & Buzz -> "FizzBuzz" 
  | Fizz -> "Fizz" 
  | Buzz -> "Buzz" 
  | _ -> "" 

let fizzBuzz = [ for i in 0 .. 100 -> findMatch i ]
```

The pattern `Fizz & Buzz` matches if both `Fizz` and `Buzz` match. This relies on the fact that the pattern is matched first, so the order is relevant in this case. I also shortened your last line a little to a style that I prefer and is a bit shorter (but opinions vary).

Alternatively, if you don't want to define too many single-purpose active patterns, you could also write a parameterized active pattern that tests whether an input is divisible by any specified number:

```
let (|DivisibleBy|_|) by n = if n%by=0 then Some DivisibleBy else None

let findMatch = function 
  | DivisibleBy 3 & DivisibleBy 5 -> "FizzBuzz" 
  | DivisibleBy 3 -> "Fizz" 
  | DivisibleBy 5 -> "Buzz" 
  | _ -> ""
```

Comment: +1 : I either forgot or never knew `&` was part of the pattern language!

Answer (score 3):

Remove (unnecessary) `Some` so that `findMatch` function takes `int` as its parameter:

```
let findMatch = function
    | FizzBuzz -> "FizzBuzz" (* Should be the first pattern *)
    | Fizz -> "Fizz"
    | Buzz -> "Buzz"
    | _ -> ""

let fizzBuzz = seq { for i in 0..100 -> i, findMatch i }
```

Comment: No, it takes `int option` due to matching on `Some Fizz`, etc.

Comment: Good catch on putting the FizzBuzz case first.